# i am adding custom html free version in my prestashop 1.7

Tags: module, prestashop-1.7

I have added one module custom html box in PrestaShop 1.7 . Module is installed but you can use it only once .can i create multiple list of htmlbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depend on the module, but if you are using htmlbox module, yes, the free version is programmed to only be used 1 time in 1 place.

But there are two options to do this without any developed module.

**1st option:**

You have the option to include these html code directly in the tpl of the activated theme.

In prestashop 1.7 version we have a new feature that, if you are in mode developer ("Advanced parameter" -> "Performance"), in the html you can see in what template is located any element.

For example, to add a code above the slider of the home page, if you inspect the element you can see this:

[image]
In the "begin" tag you have the template that you need to modify.

**2nd option:**

You can create a new module and use the display hooks correctly.

Here you have all that you need to know about the creation of modules.
http://developers.prestashop.com/module/05-CreatingAPrestaShop17Module/